# problem with first state of application state in redux kotlin

Tags: kotlin, is-empty

I'm using Redux and somewhere in application I need to check if returning data is not null, then run a function.
as you know in redux we should initialize the states like this:

```
 data class ApplicationState(
val movieByGenre : List<DomainMovieModel> = emptyList()
```

)

the problem is when I check the data ,at the very beginning level, data has been set to empty list, and it satisfies the IF statement

by the way here is the implementation inside view model

```
fun  getMovieByGenre(genreId: Int){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response=repository.getMovieByGenre(genreId)
        store.update { currentState->
            return@update currentState.copy(movieByGenre = response)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the implementation in fragment:

```
viewModel.store.stateFlow.map { it.movieByGenre }.distinctUntilChanged().asLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
                    if (it.isEmpty() ){
                             ....
                        }else{
                          .....
                        }
            }
```

Comment: Not familiar with reduxkotlin (only js redux), but what you'd do in js land is add a selector that checks the length of the list, and make that return false if the list is empty.